# Augment a mable: residuals and innovations from regression with ARMA errors model are the same

Tags: broom, fable-r, fabletools

I think there is something odd here. For example the following code gives the same values for residuals and innovations:

```
fit <- us_change %>%
  model(ARIMA(Consumption ~ Income)) %>%
    augment()
```

It seems that the `augment()` function extracts only the innovation values and uses it for the residuals from the regression too. This is seen when we extract the residuals and innovations using `residuals()`:

```
bind_rows(
    `Regression Errors` = as_tibble(residuals(fit, type = "regression")),
    `ARIMA Errors` = as_tibble(residuals(fit, type = "innovation")),
    .id = "type"
  )
```

Then the residuals and innovations are different as they should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.resid` column provided by `augment()` contains response residuals, not regression residuals. I have updated the documentation to clarify this: https://github.com/tidyverts/fabletools/commit/c0efd7166bca06450d7b18d3d0530fdeac67cce7

A response residual (`.resid`) is the error from backtransformed predictions on the original response variable. An innovation residual (`.innov`) is the error from the model (on potentially a different, transformed response variable). As your model does not transform the data, the response residuals (`.resid`) and the innovation residuals (`.innov`) are the same.

There is currently no way to obtain the regression residuals (residuals after performing regression, before applying ARIMA process) using the `augment()` function. This is something that would be nice to have in the future.